# Line Integral on polygonal path

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

[image]

How would you calculate this? Since $\textbf{F}$ has to be parametrized, could  $(x=t)$ be used? And what about $y$ and $z$? Or, since the curve is a closed path, is it automatically zero?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the curve into sum of 3 simple curves and parametrize each separately.

PS: I don't see why the path is closed. Start and end points are different.

Comment: So is it 3 curves? Or does the last one go back to the starting point? If it's a polygon, doesn't that mean they are connected?

Comment: Well, that really depends on your definition of a polygonal path. I don't think they have to be closed. And yes, it's 3 segments.

Comment: OK thank you. So I would just do the three curves separately and add them together?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. There are other ways if you are interested.

Comment: What else would work? :) Thanks.

Comment: For some 3D line integrals it is easier to use Stokes' theorem in order to express the problem as an evaluation of surface integral. I don't think it's a viable option here, though. :)